# match up ID from 2 different API sources

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have to pull data from 2 different API's for some player info.

API #1 list the data in this format

```
<PlayerId>35</PlayerId>
<Name>Joe Flacco</Name>
<Salary>6000</Salary>
```

API #2 for the same player , list the info as follows

```
<player id="9064" name="Flacco, Joe"/>
```

neither API has all the info i need , so i have to combine them to get all the data needed.

I am using API #2 for everything , aside of player Salary , for which i need get from API #1. So i think i need to assign PlayerID 35 to player id 9064 . I have about 1000 players to reassign the id for. What is best solution for doing this ? Example ? I am going to create a new json file to read this info from

Comment: I see the name format is also different in both APIs. How are you going to find who is who if none of the fields match? How will you assign id 35 to id 9064 if it has nothing in common?

Comment: i guess i'd have to build an array and manually assign 35 to 9064

Comment: So your data and ID is static? What if ID changes in the past, you'll have to manually re-write the array again. There must be better way to do it, not sure what though. Why is the API returning `HTML` rather than `JSON`? These two APIs do not have anything in common and will sure lead to inconsistency in your code pretty soon. Why can't you just go with API #1